# Como hospedar o meu site criado em Laravel no Servidor de Hospedagem? [HTTP ERROR 500]

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando hospedar meu site desenvolvido em Laravel no site de hospedagem (Locaweb), porém um erro (HTTP ERROR 500) está impossibilitando o funcionamento.

**Estrutura do arquivo:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPZxW.png

**Versão do php:** PHP Version 5.6.14

**Modiquei o public/index.php**

```
//require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
require __DIR__.'/../core/bootstrap/autoload.php';

//$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../core/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**.htaccess (é o padrão do Laravel)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

***Após essas alterações, esse erro me aparece:***

```
A página de xxx.com.br não está funcionando

xxx.com.br não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

*Uso a Locaweb como hospedagem, e  também setei a pasta core e subpastas como permissão 777.*

ps. Localmente tudo funciona.

Comment: se vc tirar o htaccess ele funciona? ( pelo menos para o erro 500 e vai da erro no seu sistema ? )

Comment: Eu já tive um problema com o Laravel no servidor, e foi por causa da permissão do public_html/index.php, setei como 644 e funcinou, veja se funciona no seu caso.

Comment: Como você fez para "instalar" o laravel no servidor? Copiou e colou os arquivos? Se fez assim o laravel deve estar com o autoloader desconfigurado e precisa do composer pra corrigir isso. Já sofri muito instalando composer na hospedagem compartilhada da locaweb e torço muito que eles tenham melhorado essa parte.

Comment: a pasta já está setado como 644. Eu consigo acessar as images, os css's (tudo dentro da public_html) mesmo com ou sem o .htaccess.

Comment: @Rafael Sim, eu copiei e colei. Existe alguma coisa que eu possa fazer?

Comment: Você configurou a pasta inicial do site Laravel em `public`?

Comment: Sim, você tem que instalar o composer, apagar a pasta vendor e rodar um composer install. Outra coisa que eu reparei agora, é que você está usando a pasta public_html (padrão da locaweb) e o laravel salva os dados na pasta public então é outra configuração que tem que ser feita.

Comment: Não se esqueça de dar permissão de escrita na pasta `storage` também

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Não configurei. Existe algum tutorial para fazer isso?

Comment: @denalioasis o Laravel por padrão é inicial pela pasta `public` se o servidor não tiver como configurar o site realmente não funciona e pelo que eu sei o referido servidor não tem isso.